# array_merge function doesn't work properly

Tags: php, arrays

I have to arrays:

```
Array
(
    [58812b9d2e069a0680000e06] => Array
        (
            [color] => #FF00FF
        )

)
```

and

```
Array
(
    [58812b9d2e069a0680000e06] => Array
        (
            [color] => #FF0000
        )

)
```

Output of `array_merge($arr1, $arr2)` only shows `$arr1` value. Could someone help me with this?

**Edit 1 -I want to merge them, Even if they have same key.**

Comment: It's merging fine; you are using the same key, so one of the values goes bye bye...

Comment: @I'L'l Thanks. But still I want to merge them with same key. Because they have different values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ar1 = array("58812b9d2e069a0680000e06" => array("color" => "#FF00FF"));
$ar2 = array("58812b9d2e069a0680000e06" => array("color" => "#FF0000"));
$result = array_merge_recursive($ar1, $ar2);
print_r($result);
```

---

array_merge_recursive — Merge two or more arrays recursively

Answer (score 0):

```
$array_1 = array("a"=>"demo 1", "b"=>"blogs");

$array_1 = array("z"=>"demo 2", "d"=>"articles");

print_r(array_merge_recursive($array_1, $array_2));
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.